# What does this blurry technobabble on the Project Genesis Summary splash screen say?

Tags: star-trek, the-wrath-of-khan

[image]

It seems to contain a mixture of technical words and numbers.

Is there a clearer image available, or does anyone have the patience to decipher it?

Comment: Does anyone actually know where this comes from?   I found it via Google search while researching another question.   I couldn't actually find it in my copy of the movie.

Comment: It's at about 43:45 of the Blu-Ray version, in the middle of Carol Marcus's summary of the Genesis Project. The scene occurs in Kirk's quarters where the trio are trying to learn what Genesis is.

Comment: Un-modified Blu-Ray frame in case it offers any advantage over the one we already have (although it doesn't really look like it): http://i.imgur.com/OGBnSdd.jpg

Comment: @hobbs, I believe it does.   Thanks!    Revising my earlier attempt.

Comment: Tried manipulating the contrast, but [wasn't able to get much out of it](https://i.imgur.com/rTc73PE.png). Also tried to see if I could work from the reverse angle; figure out the font used, and then use that and blurring to reconstruct the text. Unfortunately, while 1982 makes a decent cutoff for fonts, there's still just too many (and too inaccessible) to really narrow it down. Helvetica comes close, but the tail on the "G" just doesn't match quite right.

Comment: @Mwr247, I have no doubt that a sufficiently motivated sufficiently sophisticated entity could apply a machine learning or adaptive algorithm to fit the transformation from the original font through all the distortions and then easily determine the original text by brute force.   Somehow we just need to entice the right quasi-governmental or cyber-crime related (pro or con) organization.   Or find the right nerds.

Answer (score 26):

Adding this Community wiki answer if people want to piece this together over time.  If anyone can produce a plainly legible image or an existing transcript, feel free to add as your own answer instead.   Otherwise, **edit at will**:

## `GENESIS ◑ DEVICE`

`1N.AC41.??AB4377.AC.GENESIS.LB.CLAS.????.SCHEMA.CZCY.???????=??`

---

`1N.AC41.??AB4377.AC.GENESIS.LB.CLAS.????.SCHEMA.CZCY.???????=??` (same line as up top)
`TECHSCHEMA.04377.MX2000.TEC.SUBSCHEM=0.SUB????Y.SCI=7.???=1 
SC1.1.AT7.SPECENERGY.????-1???.FEMTOJOULE.SOL.????
SC2.5.AT0.MA???ON.EXEMPT.LEV??-???????MODULARITY.???-B
SC3.4.AT1.BIO.???=02521/FORM.BIO.DNA.AS75H.FORM.TRANS*RAND
SC4.5.AT3.THERMODY,14,ENTROP.SPEC.NEVER?.FACT.141.COHERENT
SC5.5.AT1.ELECTROMAG.SPECT=ALL.BANDWIDTH.TMIC-0?.???
SC6.5.AT2.CHEM.TRANSMUTE=130.EL.VAL.[81/?=6,C=12,U=230]
SC7.1.AT1.DIST,SCALE[?]POSTREACT=???-PARSEC
EN1.1.AT0.MECHFILES.064.TORP.????-??.METH.CONFID=????=0044???-1REV(70)`

`PR.0.'DR CAROL MARCUS'.INV?.PROJ=GENESIS.SECTION.0001
AC.1.ENG/20.COMSEC.4-1.TERRA.OFF.'DR D E VALLIS' (???-????).CODE.10
AC.2.SCI/19.COMSEC.4-4.TERRA.OFF.'DR R N GREEN'(?41-1SCI).CODE.??`

`???????.REFR=FORBID:STAPL.TCOM.ORD.????418.????CAT.....`

Comment: Just for grinding through that text you have my upvote.  My eyes gave out about a minute into it even with the updated image.

Comment: *Femtojoules.s01.Body* on the third line

Comment: @Richard, yeah I got it.   That's an impossibly useless unit at the planetary scale.

Comment: They like big numbers and they cannot lie...

Comment: My God, it's full of JCL.

Answer (score 18):

I took your image and ran it through some [image deconvolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deconvolution) software I had lying around.  The software is better at correcting lens focus problems than the rather obvious resolution problem your image has, but it did clean it up a bit.

[image: deconvoluted image]

As you can see what's on screen is mostly just garbage text and numbers, but there are a few relevant strings.  "CAROL MARCUS" appears on the line fourth from the bottom.  "ELECTROMAG_SPECT" appears on the line eighth from the bottom.  And the word "GENESIS" appears on the line directly below the big "GENESIS DEVICE" header.

Comment: Damn, I *just* start working on this question and a new answer pops up! +1 :-)

Comment: Good work.   I was creating the community wiki answer to crowdsource this at the same time you were working on this.   My suggestion is that we keep both answers, that everyone upvote @KyleJones for his work, and that people edit [this answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/110325/3823) to determine the complete text.

Comment: Can you improve hobbs' capture?