# What was the first 3D CGI used in Star Trek?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, history-of, star-trek-tos, cgi

This means I'm seeking the first three-dimensionally computer-modeled and rendered imagery used in *Star Trek*.

We know there was extensive 3D CGI used in *DS9* (Odo) and *Voyager* (USS Voyager).   But what is the earliest use in *TNG* or any of the *TOS* movies?

Note that to satisfy this question, there needs to have been a meaningful model built in 3D and then rendered, as I'm sure there was a lot of post-processing done by computer in TNG and there were many 2D images generated for effects (e.g. Okudagrams) and the line between what would constitute computer-generated 2D images and merely digital image manipulation would be kind of blurry.   Manually generated images from multiple views that were meant to appear 3D do not count.

Comment: Obsolete speculation:  "The Game" is the first obvious example, but it is not until season 5. I imagine there is an earlier occurrence. The blob that casts a shadow in "Identity Crisis" also comes to mind, but I don't even know if this was not meres a 2D image.

Comment: In “The Dauphin,” CGI was likely used to show the transformation of the Allasomorph into other species.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

According to the [CGI article on Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/CGI):

> The very first CGI used was in [Star Trek II: The Wrath of Khan](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek_II:_The_Wrath_of_Khan), where Lucasfilm Graphics Group, then a subsidiary of [Industrial Light & Magic (ILM)](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Industrial_Light_%26_Magic), was responsible for the "[Project Genesis](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Project_Genesis)" demonstration sequence effect, the very first fully textured 3D CGI representation shown in the motion picture business to a general public.

So per to the article, which is thoroughly detailed on the use of CGI in the franchise, the first use of a fully textured 3D CGI then would be the Genesis Effect, seen here (1982):

As luck would have it, there's actually "making of" video available on youtube:

Comment: Of course!   I didn't think of that!

Comment: Perhaps you want this link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=52XlyMbxxh8&t=54s

Comment: @ThePopMachine Included that one first in place of the placeholder image. Still wanted to include the making of, since it's pretty informative of how they pulled it off at the time :)

Comment: Sure, but the video quality in the Making Of doesn't really do it justice.

Comment: The team that worked on this would later be a part of starting Pixar - http://www.pixartouchbook.com/blog/2009/7/16/star-trek.html

Comment: [Related question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/110319/what-does-this-blurry-technobabble-on-the-project-genesis-summary-splash-screen)

Comment: And if you watch real close you can see a slot cut through a mountain to allow the point of view to pass through without hitting (around 2:52 on the making of video).

Comment: Quite interesting that this CGI sequence was part of a video presetation depicting something which hadn't happened yet, so also a CGI sequence in the context of the story. This leaves the question about when CGI was first used to represent something which was real within the narrative fiction.

Comment: I love how they were able to generate this masterpiece (in 1982!) but the onscreen text looks like crap.

Comment: @ThePopMachine By "crap", are you referring to the font choices of most of the screens, or specifically the illegibility of the Genesis Device screen? The former I agree is pretty poor, the latter I think had more to do with how it carried over onto film.

Comment: @Mwr247:   Well, the font choices, yes, but I was referring to both all the large text that appears in the film itself and all the titles and credits in the Making-Of video.

Answer (score 15):

With regard to TNG, the first explicitly CGI object seen in the show is the gigantic force-field erected by Q at approx 4 minutes in.

[image]

We have confirmation (from Wil Wheaton, the actor who portrayed Wesley Crusher) that this was indeed a computer-generated effect rather than a physical model or a video-effect.

> "There's a mystery at Farpoint, and he's totally going to solve
> it...just as soon as he figures out how to get past this **giant CGI net**
> that's arrived out of nowhere and is cockblocking his ship."
>
> <sub><sup>[Memories of the Future - Volume 1](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6977336-memories-of-the-future---volume-1)</sup></sub>

Comment: Sounds right, but do we really know Wil Weaton is doing anything more than speculating like we are?

Comment: Also, do we know how the planets in the opening credits were generated?

Comment: @ThePopMachine - I believe they were matte paintings with various lighting effects and VFX matting **but not CGI**

Comment: What about the Enterprise? It sure looks ray traced to me, we see it in the intro and it is also the first thing we see after the intro credits, while Picard does his captain's log entry.

Comment: @JamesHollis - It's (mostly) a physical effect with some lighting effects. Not CGI as far as I'm aware

Comment: @JamesHollis:   It was a notable story at the time, that Voyager was the first series to use a CGI titular starship and not a model.

Comment: People may be very interested in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vHOpSrDwZNM)

Comment: For a moment I read that as being a computer effect from Wheaton, instead of a confirmation from Wheaton and I wondered if Wheaton actually was a genius programmer or something. (Also, typo: *h* in Wheaton.)

Comment: @muru: I thought the same thing, actually. I suggest re-ordering that sentence a bit so that it's clear that the CGI effect didn't come from Wheaton.

Comment: @Ellesedil - Shut up, Wesley!

Answer (score 9):

As for the first rendered 3D *object*, I would say that would be

### The Crystalline Entity, from S1E13, *Datalore*

From Memory Alpha: [Crystalline Entity](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Crystalline_Entity)

> In its very first appearance, the Crystalline Entity was one of the very first CGI sequences used in the Star Trek franchise. It was built and rendered by Chris Alsop at The Post Group.

Comment: What about the Q mesh from Encounter at Farpoint?

Comment: @Valorum - as a force field, it's arguable whether or not it constitutes an *object*.

Comment: @Jules, asker is asking for *any* imagery. There does not appear to be any requirement for *what* that imagery is of.